# Ruby / Rails - Reverse Migration - DDL to Ruby Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ddl, migration

Any tools in Ruby or Rails that would allow me to extract from database all the table schema and generate Ruby equivalent "DLL" statements?

Something that would allow me to port schema from say Microsoft SQL Server to Postgres, or MySQL to Sqlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails/ActiveRecord, you can use `rake db:schema:dump` to generate db/schema.rb, and `rake db:schema:load` to load it into a database.