# Easiest way to port a data model to Rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, reverse-engineering, database-migration

I have designed a data model which has almost 24 tables. I have finished specifying the relations and all the data types are finalized. Now, I want to convert it to migrations in Rails.

I have all the scripts ready for it to be created in MySQL. Is there any tool that converts all the table creation queries into a single Rails migration file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done it myself but according to [this post on the ruby forums](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/199012)

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

should be sufficient (delete the schema.rb beforehand).

The almost same question here on SO: [Ruby / Rails - Reverse Migration - DDL to Ruby Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428499/ruby-rails-reverse-migration-ddl-to-ruby-code)